# SQLiteConnection.CreateTable<>() Throwing SEHException (Windows IoT & Raspberry Pi)

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to connect to and use an SQLite database with the following code:

```
private SQLiteConnection con;
    //private TableQuery<Reading> readings;
    private TableQuery<Setting> settings;
    private double radius, height, totalVolume, maxLitres;
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
        con = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);

        //Createing table if they already don't exist
        con.CreateTable<Setting>();
        con.CreateTable<Reading>();

        settings = con.Table<Setting>();
        //readings = con.Table<Reading>();

        con.Insert(new Setting() { name = "radius", value = 0.8128 });
        con.Insert(new Setting() { name = "height", value = 1.6256 });

        radius = getSetting(settings, "radius").value;
        height = getSetting(settings, "height").value;

        totalVolume = Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2) * height;
        maxLitres = totalVolume * 1000;

        WebServer server = new WebServer();

        //await ThreadPool.RunAsync(workItem => { server.Start(); });
        server.Start();

    }

public sealed class Setting
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }

    }
```

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Getting this error on this line:

```
con.CreateTable<Setting>();
```

It was working but now is not.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Show the entire stack trace.

Comment: What's your windows iot core version?